# formatting date in ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, date

I have a date in the format `05/22/2011 13:10 Eastern Time (US & Canada)`

How can I convert that into a date object? This is what I used to parse the date from sting but I'm getting invalid date error.

```
str = "05/22/2011 13:10 Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
Date.strptime(str, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sting: `05/22/2011 13:10 Eastern Time (US & Canada)`.

Here is a number of mistakes in your pattern:

- Month is a first argument
- Day is a second
- Here is no any seconds in your time, only hours and minutes

Also your string includes Date and Time as well, so you'd better to use `DateTime` class instead of `Date` class:

```
Date.strptime(str, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %Z")
#=> Sun, 22 May 2011
```

or

```
DateTime.strptime(str, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %Z")
#=> Sun, 22 May 2011 13:10:00 -0500
```

To work with datetime you should require it first:

```
require 'date'
dt = DateTime.strptime("05/22/2011 13:10 Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %Z")
#=> #<DateTime: 353621413/144,-5/24,2299161>
dt.to_s
#=> "2011-05-22T13:10:00-05:00"
dt.hour
#=> 13
...
```

Comment: DateTime.strptime("05/22/2011 13:10 Eastern Time (US & Canada)", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %Z") still gives me invalid date.

Comment: And I was testing it in Rails console :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 bugs in your call to Date.strptime

1) The date and month are reversed

2) There is no seconds field in your string